# Collection users - mLabs

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I tried to obtain users API by mongolabs, but always return an empty list
It's strange because when I connect to mongo shell, users are displayed correctly.

Anybody know what is happening?

Comment: Please show us what you have implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution is:

https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/{database}/users?apiKey={myAPIKEy}